# Non-blocking sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, networking

I was looking at the socket programming module of the python standard library and I noticed a fucntion `socket.setblocking`. The documentation mentioned that setting a socket to non blocking mode would mean that an error would be raised if the data was not sent out through the socket immediately or if data was not available upon trying to read from the socket.

I'm having trouble understanding usecases in which this function might be useful. I'm working on a Linux machine(just in case the answer to this would be OS dependent).

Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html

Comment: Are you familiar with exceptions? Because what it says it that you can use exceptions to do control-flow based on whether you received/not-received data or whether you was able to send/not-send data. The other option would be to use the return value, but it would be hard to choose the return value of, for example, `recv`: the only option would be the empty string, but it is already used to signal that there isn't anything else to read (e.g. when reading from files).

Answer (score 0):

When you set the socket to blocking, the socket waits for the specified time on that socket. While it is waiting on the socket, your program cannot do anything. At the end of the wait time it raises an error. Sometimes you dont want blocking to occur.
A good use case for this might be when you are sending an receiving message on a single threaded program using multiple sockets. You don't want to block on a socket while waiting to send or receive messages rather you may want to check if there are messages to send or receive for each of the sockets hence you would want no blocking time or limited blocking time while you loop through the sockets. [This](http://pymotw.com/2/socket/) will provide a more in depth discussion of python sockets.